# Mocking react-router-dom useHistory and other hooks with jest

Tags: reactjs, testing, mocking, jestjs, react-router-dom

I have a CRA and Typescript (.tsx) application. I'm trying to write a test for a component that needs `useHistory` and `useRouteMatch` but it return the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined`.

**The component:**

```js
const SidebarTreeNav: React.FC<Props> = ( { tree, expanded } ) => {
  const history = useHistory();
  let { url } = useRouteMatch();

  const handleClick = useCallback(
    ( path: string ) => history.push(`${ url }/${ path }`),
    [ history ]);

  return (
    <SidebarTreeNavView expanded={ expanded ?? [ '0' ] }>
      <SidebarTreeNavBlock handleClick={ handleClick } tree={ tree } node={ 0 } />
    </SidebarTreeNavView>
  );
};

export default SidebarTreeNav;
```

**The Test:**

```js
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => {
      const originalModule = jest.requireActual('react-router-dom');

      return {
        __esModule: true,
        ...originalModule,
        useRouteMatch: { url: '/entry' },
        useHistory: jest.fn(),
      };
    });

    shallow = createShallow();
    wrapper = shallow(<SidebarTreeNav tree={ [] } />);
  });

  it('<SidebarTreeNav /> should be defined', () => {
    expect(wrapper).toBeDefined();
  });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably this answer is not needed for you anymore, but I'll post it for future reference.

First, you defined `jest.mock` in the wrong place, it has to be static, not mocked before every component mount - that solves your `useHistory` error.
Second, you mocked `useRouteMatch` in a wrong way, it would've thrown that `useRouteMatch` is not a function.
Third, why do you need that `__esModule: true`?

Anyways, here's my working solution (I removed some parts that were not relevant):

SidebarTreeNav component:

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'react';
import { useHistory, useRouteMatch } from 'react-router-dom';

const SidebarTreeNav = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const { url } = useRouteMatch();

  const handleClick = useCallback(
    (path: string) => history.push(`${url}/${path}`),
    [history]
  );

  // eslint-disable-next-line jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events,jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions
  return <div onClick={() => handleClick(url)}>expanded</div>;
};

export default SidebarTreeNav;
```

test file:

```
import { shallow, ShallowWrapper } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';

import SidebarTreeNav from './SideBarTreeNav';

jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => {
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual('react-router-dom');

  return {
    ...originalModule,
    useHistory: jest.fn(),
    useRouteMatch: jest.fn(() => {
      return { url: '/entry' };
    }),
  };
});

describe('whatever', () => {
  let wrapper: ShallowWrapper;

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<Temporary />);
  });

  it('<SidebarTreeNav /> should be defined', () => {
    expect(wrapper).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

A side note: it's really hard to work with your example because you posted just some part of your code, next time please add a fully replicated js fiddle.

Comment: Really helpful! `jest.requireActual` is a powerful function on jest mocks.